# jquery down state and Load default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<head>
<script>
        var specs = {
            'home' : {desc: 'Images/homeon.png', src:'Images/homeoff.png'},
            'about' : {desc: 'Images/aboutuson.png', src:'Images/aboutusoff.png'},
            'contact' : {desc: 'Images/contacton.png', src:'Images/contactoff.png'}
        }
        function toggleContent(footer)
        {
            document.getElementById('text').src = specs[footer].desc;
            document.getElementById('link').src = specs[footer].src;
        }
window.onload = function() {
    toggleContent("home");
}    
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="product-toggle">
<img onclick="toggleContent('home')" src="Images/affinitynav.png" width="166" height="39">
<img onclick="toggleContent('about')" src="Images/ancienttalesnav.png" width="166" height="39">
<img onclick="toggleContent('contact')" src="Images/dhivenav.png" width="166" height="39">
</div>

<img src="" id="link">
<img src="" id="text">
</body>
```

I need every image to have a down state, so the users know where they are.
Basically like on the image here https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6X8uGoS_xDwMlo4V3d5VzluUHc/edit

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'm new here, easy to make mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
    toggleContent("home");
}
```

Add this to the end of your script block. When your page finishes loading, this will be executed and set your default images.

Comment: ok that worked for the default state, thanks, now only to figure out the button down state part

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<div id="product-toggle">
<img onclick="toggleContent('home')" src="Images/affinitynav.png" width="166" height="39" id="home">
<img onclick="toggleContent('about')" src="Images/ancienttalesnav.png" width="166" height="39" id="about">
<img onclick="toggleContent('contact')" src="Images/dhivenav.png" width="166" height="39" id="contact">
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
    var specs = {
            'home' : {desc: 'Images/homeon.png', src:'Images/homeoff.png'},
            'about' : {desc: 'Images/aboutuson.png', src:'Images/aboutusoff.png'},
            'contact' : {desc: 'Images/contacton.png', src:'Images/contactoff.png'}
        }
        function toggleContent(footer)
        {
            var imgObj = document.getElementById('product-toggle').getElementsByTagName('img');
            for(var i=0;i<imgObj.length;i++) {
                imgObj[i].className = ""
            }
            document.getElementById(footer).className=footer+'active';
            document.getElementById('text').src = specs[footer].desc;
            document.getElementById('link').src = specs[footer].src;

        }
window.onload = function() {
    toggleContent('home')
}
```

Comment: what else you require?

Comment: Well its hard to explain on English, but i'll try :)
I got 3 images that change the div contents as you see, but i need when the image is clicked to have a DOWN state that indicates the currently selected field. (you can see better from the image i posted), and thank you so much for the help!

Comment: if i understood what you want then you just need to add an active class, and if you found the answer above correct then mark as correct so that even others are aware of the solutions

Comment: I think you did, but my problem is that every image had its own down state (another image) so if home has lets say homedown, about has aboutdown etc. All the tutorials and guides i found change the entire menu class of all the butons not just single buttons. if you understood anything i just said :S

Comment: so you mean there is different class for different link. Like home has a different select class and about has a different select class?

Comment: i have updated my post above but using jquery this would have been simpler

Comment: well this was the only solution I managed to find that I acctualy knew how it works.. If you have a diff solution that does the same thing and its easier, im opened to anything. And thanks again for the update :) wish I could vote up the post, but no rep yet

Comment: you can vote i guess, btw i assume you saw the above code. now it adds different class to different image. If you want a specific className you can even do that by keeping it in the specs array and getting it from there.